# To open spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I open a shared google docs spreadsheet with 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc12s4562") , I would like to know if somebody is reading the spreadsheet and if it's true , I would like to display a popup to inform the reader .
Do you think it is possible to do that ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to "detect" when someone *opens* a spreadsheet but it's not like that. What you have is the `onOpen` and `onEdit` events that you can hook to trigger your script and then you can popup something to the user.

Popups can not be arbitrarily triggered by the script like that. And there's no way to know if someone is viewing a spreadsheet, you only have `onEdit`.

If you want to warn your users that the script is working on the spreadsheet and they should wait a little. You could change some visual setting on the spreadsheet itself. Maybe changing the background color of some or all cells. Or even protecting a sheet programatically to really avoid concurrency issues.